# PHP: Is it possible to return multiple values from a function?

Tags: php, function, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple returns from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-function)

I have a function that should return several values. Is this possible, perhaps with an array? If so, how would I reference that array? Do I have any alternatives to using an array?