# returning three variable to function and checking them

Tags: php

Hello please help me out regarding returning the variable from the function 
I am return three variable from the function likw this

```
return $data 
return $success 
return $error
```

calling from

```
$check  =$user->search($result);
```

now to put some condition according to the variable received .The problem i am facing is that how can i get the name of the vairable which i have received . i want to receive it by name not by value
like

```
if($check == $data )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Is it possible to return multiple values from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579892/php-is-it-possible-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function) and a [couple of others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multiple+return+values+[php]).

Comment: Use Python and you can return a tuple and assign the elements of it using a sane syntax ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function myfunc() {
   ... do stuff ...
   $values = array($data, $success, $error);
   return($values);
}

$data = myfunc();
echo "Data is ", $data[0];
```

`return` can only return a single thing, and it "aborts" the function, so you cannot have 2 or more returns in a row - only the first one would ever execute. So, the workaround is to return a container which contains all the values you need. In this case, i've used an array, but return can "return" anything - you could have an object passed back if you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return more than one variable from a function.  I suggest making an array, and returning that.

```
return array('data' => $data, 'success' => $success, 'error' => $error);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't return three variables that way. `$success` and `$error` will never be returned, because the function ends after the first `return $data`.

If you want to return three values, you can do it like this:

```
return array($data, $success, $error);
```

And call it like this:

```
list($data, $success, $error) = $user->search($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the original poster is trying to return 3 variables, but rather has multiple control paths and returns something different based on some conditions.

```
public function search($r) {
    ...
    return array('data'    => $data);
    ...
    return array('success' => $success);
    ...
    return array('error'   => $error);
}

$check = $user->search($result);
switch(key($check)) {
    case 'data':
        // handle data
    break;

    case 'success':
        // handle success
    break;

    case 'error':
        // handle error
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The clean solution would be to return a dataset (e.g. an array) on success, and throw an exception if an error occurs. Using this method would eliminate the need for the variable $success.

When you call the method implemented this way, you can go like this:

```
try
{
    $data = $someObject->someFunction($some_parameter);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // error handling code path
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure about your use case, but from the looks of the variables you expect, I would advise to turn them into reference parameters:

```
function search($data, &$success, &$error) {
```

This is what many native PHP functions do, and an applicable idiom for status variables like yours. The disadvantage is that you *always* have to invoke the method with the extra parameters then:

```
$check  = $user->search($result, $success, $error);
```

Does not address your (not solvable in the simplistic manner you tried) `..how can i get the name of the vairable which i have received`, but I'm not quite sure what you meant or intended there.