# PHP 5 how to call multiple values from one function?

Tags: php, oop, class, design-patterns

If I have the following class example:

```
<?php
class Person
{
    private $prefix;
    private $givenName;
    private $familyName;
    private $suffix;

    public function setPrefix($prefix)
    {
        $this->prefix = $prefix;
    }

    public function getPrefix()
    {
        return $this->prefix;
    }

    public function setGivenName($gn)
    {
        $this->givenName = $gn;
    }

    public function getGivenName()
    {
        return $this->givenName;
    }

    public function setFamilyName($fn)
    {
        $this->familyName = $fn;
    }

    public function getFamilyName() 
    {
        return $this->familyName;
    }

    public function setSuffix($suffix)
    {
        $this->suffix = $suffix;
    }

    public function getSuffix()
    {
        return $suffix;
    }

}

$person = new Person();
$person->setPrefix("Mr.");
$person->setGivenName("John");

echo($person->getPrefix());
echo($person->getGivenName());

?>
```

I there a way in PHP (5.4 preferably), to combine these return values into one function, this way it models a little bit more like the revealing module pattern in JavaScript?

**UPDATE:**
OK, I am now beginning to learn that within PHP, it is normative to return a single value from a function, but you "can" return an array of multiple values.  This is the ultimate answer to my question and what I will dive into some practices with this understanding.

small example -

```
function fruit () {
return [
 'a' => 'apple', 
 'b' => 'banana'
];
}
echo fruit()['b'];
```

Also an article I ran across on stackoverflow on the topic...
[PHP: Is it possible to return multiple values from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579892/php-is-it-possible-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function)

Good luck!

Comment: Why don't you just return an array ?? or what exactly are you expecting ?

Comment: I'm new to OOP with PHP, but it just looks like the code can be condensed, in the sense of knowing what is being returned and whats not, why scroll down a million lines of code to see what function is being returned, when you can control all of your returned functions from a single constructor function.

Comment: Ofcourse you can! Just return the object himself: `return $this;`

Comment: ok, that makes sense to me.  I just need to learn how to properly return this when it comes down to returning selective PHP functions in a class

Comment: You could probably use the magic [__set and __get](http://ch1.php.net/__set) for this.

Comment: Sounds good - I'll look into that Louis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
public function getAll() {
    return(array('prefix' => $this->prefix, 'givenName' => $this->giveName, etc...));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You sound like you want the [`__get()` magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get).

```
class Thing {

private $property;

public function __get($name) {
    if( isset( $this->$name ) {
        return $this->$name;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Cannot __get() class property: ' . $name);
    }
}

} // -- end class Thing --

$athing = new Thing();
$prop = $athing->property;
```

In the case that you want all of the values returned at once, as in Marc B's example, I'd simplify the class design for it thusly:

```
class Thing {

private $properties = array();

public function getAll() {
    return $properties;
}

public function __get($name) {
    if( isset( $this->properties[$name] ) {
        return $this->properties[$name];
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Cannot __get() class property: ' . $name);
    }
}

} // -- end class Thing --

$athing = new Thing();
$prop   = $athing->property;
$props  = $athing-> getAll();
```

Comment: Or just rename the private to public and remove all those useless methods

Comment: *OR* leave it how it is and think of the case where you want to allow public *read* access, but leave write access restricted. Also, because you can write your own accessors you can greatly extend what $obj->prop really does in the background.

Comment: Thank you Sammitch for the help! This looks very interesting.