# Returning two values from a function

Tags: php, function, return-value

Is it possible to return two values when calling a function that would output the values?

For example, I have this:

```
<?php
    function ids($uid = 0, $sid = '')
    {
        $uid = 1;
        $sid = md5(time());

        return $uid;
        return $sid;
    }

    echo ids();
?>
```

Which will output `1`. I want to chose what to ouput, e.g. `ids($sid)`, but it will still output `1`.

Is it even possible?

Comment: This page ought to be updated [for PHP 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-a-function/48166310#48166310), [destructuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Parallel_assignment) (though that question is ambiguous).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can only return one value. But you can use an [array](http://php.net/language.types.array) that itself contains the other two values:

```
return array($uid, $sid);
```

Then you access the values like:

```
$ids = ids();
echo $ids[0];  // uid
echo $ids[1];  // sid
```

You could also use an associative array:

```
return array('uid' => $uid, 'sid' => $sid);
```

And accessing it:

```
$ids = ids();
echo $ids['uid'];
echo $ids['sid'];
```

Comment: @YouBook: You need to change the way you process the return value too.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, didn't read your edits. Anyway, great answer. :) *waits till I can accept this*

Comment: @YouBook, check out `list` in my answer below. Very convenient feature.

Answer (score 25):

Return an array or an object if you need to return multiple values. For example:

```
function foo() {
    return array(3, 'joe');
}

$data = foo();
$id = $data[0];
$username = $data[1];

// or:
list($id, $username) = foo();
```

Comment: +1 for hinting at objects as an alternative, adding semantical meaning. However, in time-critical situations, arrays might be a tiny bit faster (if in doubt, benchmark just to be sure).

Answer (score 23):

You can use an array and the list function to get the info easily :

```
function multi($a,$b) {
   return array($a,$b);
}

list($first,$second) = multi(1,2);
```

I hope this will help you

Jerome

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because here you return several variables and you can directly access them without "accessing" the array.

Answer (score 6):

```
function ids($uid = 0, $sid = '') 
{ 
    $uid = 1; 
    $sid = md5(time()); 

    return array('uid' => $uid,
                 'sid' => $sid
                );     
} 

$t = ids(); 
echo $t['uid'],'<br />';
echo $t['sid'],'<br />';
```

Answer (score 5):

Many possibilities:

```
// return array
function f() {
    return array($uid, $sid);
}
list($uid, $sid) = f();
$uid;
$sid;

// return object
function f() {
    $obj = new stdClass;
    $obj->uid = $uid;
    $obj->sid = $sid;
    return $obj;
}
$obj->uid;
$obj->sid;

// assign by reference
function f(&$uid, &$sid) {
    $uid = '...';
    $sid = '...';
}
f($uid, $sid);
$uid;
$sid;
```

Comment: I think better assign by reference... but this can be dangers!

Answer (score 2):

```
return array('uid' => $uid, 'sid' => $sid);
```

and then access it like

```
$dinga = ids();
extract($dinga);
```

[extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) will make uid and sid variable. So then you can use $uid and $sid.

Comment: this is another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Pass by reference would be a solution. 
This way you:

- return a value as you normally would
- and modify the second (the one passed by refference to the function)

An example:

```
function foo(&$var) // notice the & in front of the parameter passed
{
    $var++;
    return 1;
}

$a=5;
echo foo($a);
// echoes 1, the returned value
echo $a;
// $a is now 6
```