# Multiple responses from function

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to have this function return multiple results in array(?).

So basically instead of running `lookup("354534", "name");` and `lookup("354534", "date");` mutiple times for different results, how can I return both name & date from that function, then echo it out so I only have to use the function once?

```
    function lookup($data, $what)
 {
  $json = file_get_contents("http://site.com/".$data.".json");
  $output = json_decode($json, true);  
  echo $output['foo'][''.$what.''];
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple returns from function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the function return the whole JSON result:

```
function lookup($data)
{
    $json = file_get_contents("http://site.com/".$data.".json");
    $output = json_decode($json, true);  
    return $output["foo"];
}
```

then you can do

```
$result = lookup("354534");

echo $result["name"];
echo $result["date"];
```

This is really a good idea, because otherwise, you'll make the (slow) file_get_contents request multiple times, something you want to avoid.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't want to run it multiple times, and it made no sense doing so. I just didn't know how to do it until now, thanks pekka!

Comment: Actually, when I run the code I get Message: Undefined index: date. Any reason why?

Comment: @user the json probably doesn't contain a field named "date" in that case

Comment: @pekka, I just verified it does contain "date" by going to the json url. It worked the previous (multiple time) way I was doing it, but it's not working this way

Comment: @user can you do a `print_r($output);`

Comment: @user ah sorry, I overlooked the "foo" in your question. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

substitue `echo` in your function with `return`, and return the entire array:

```
function lookup($data){
  ...
  return $output;
  }

...

$results = lookup($someData);
echo $results['name'] . $results['date'];
```