# Can a function have multiple return value types in PHP?

Tags: php, function, return

Is there a way I can have my PHP function return a different value type?

The following code should explain what I mean:

```
<?php
    public function test($value){
        if($value == 1){
            return "SUCCESS";
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

On one condition I'm returning a string, otherwise I'm returning a Boolean. Is that allowed/possible?

Comment: It's not possible if you care about good practices :)

Comment: Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: This seems like a terrible example. Why not just return `true`?

Comment: @BrendanLong I believe this was an example not a 'real world' example.

Comment: This may or may not be the intent of Stack Overflow question *[Multiple returns from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906)*.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. PHP is loosely typed, so any variable can take any type. Function return values are no exception.

Comment: And worthwhile to add that *many* native php functions do this. In fact, the manual calls this the "mixed" return type.

Comment: @chris And even if the return type isn't mixed, the function normally returns either the specified return type or false/null. So yeah, quite common :)

Comment: It is not possible in PHP 7 with scrict mode enabled

Comment: @PiKey It is possible, as long as you do not specify an explicit return type. Strict mode has no impact on untyped code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible (but not advisable).

You should at least declare it in your Javadoc comment

```
/**
 * @param int $value
 * @return mixed string|boolean
 **/
public function test($value){
    if($value == 1){
        return "SUCCESS";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Even PHP's built in functions do it sometimes (e.g mysql_connect => boolean | resource link)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's allowed, not like in C, Java, ..., where you have to define the return.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed. However, it is not advisable in the case you gave. For an example where this makes sense, take a look at e.g. [strpos()](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder about this myself, why return something that is different? So the receiving end gets two things to check?

I think I have settled on returning an empty version of the type or an array with a status element myself.

Two examples, how things can change within a function/method, and you are basically forced to check more than expected:

```
<?php
    function test($value) {
        if ($value == 1) {
            $local = successFunction($value);
            return $local;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    $res = test(1);
    if ($res) {
       echo "Are we OK? Right? No? What is this?";
    }
```

Version 2

```
    function test($value) {
        if ($value == 1) {
            $local = successFunction($value);
            return $local;
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    $res = test(1);
    if (!empty($res)) {
        echo "More likely we are OK.";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

> Is that allowed/possible?

Yep.