# Two different return types in PHP function

Tags: php, function, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple returns from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-function)

Is it possible to return 2 results in the same PHP function? One is an array, the other is an integer. Could someone give me an example?

Comment: http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Answer (score 4):

```
function functest() {
  return array(1, "two");
}

list($first,$second) = functest();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from returning whatever type you like from a function. You can return a dictionary with multiple keys, or an array of mixed object types, or whatever. Anything you like.

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = $some_object;
$arr[] = 3;
$arr["a_string"] = "foo";
return $arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to *simulate* multiple return values (the first two, however, are just a kind of wrapping of multiple values into one):

1. Return an `array` with the two values: `return array($myInt, $myArr);` (see e.g. [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).)
2. Create a dedicated wrapper object and return this: `return new MyIntAndArrayWrapper($myInt, $myArr);`
3. Add an "output argument" to the function signature: `function myFunc(&$myIntRetVal) { ... return $myArr; }` (see e.g. [`preg_match(..., &$matches)`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
function myfunction() {
  //Calculate first result
  $arrayresult=...

  //Calculate second result
  $intresult=...

  //Move in with each other . don't be shy!
  return array($arrayresult,$intresult)
}
```

and in the other code

```
$tmp=myfunction();
$arrayresult=$tmp[0];
$intresult=$tmp[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible since PHP doesn't use strong typing. Just return the value you want in whatever type you want. A simple example:

```
function dual($type) {
  if ($type === 'integer')
    return 4711;
  else
    return 'foo';
}
```

You can use several functions on the caller side to see which type you got, for example: [gettype](http://php.net/gettype), [is_int](http://php.net/is_int), [is_a](http://php.net/is_a).