# PHP function returning two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, function, return, concatenation

I have a function and I need it to return two arrays.

I know a function can only return one variable .. is there a way to return my two arrays?

If I concatenate them, how can I separate them cleanly when out of the function?

Comment: actually the same as the accepted answer, just with lots more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-function#answer-3579950

Answer (score 65, accepted):

No need to concatenate: just return array of two arrays, like this:

```
function foo() {
    return array($firstArray, $secondArray);
}
```

... then you will be able to assign these arrays to the local variables with [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php), like this:

```
list($firstArray, $secondArray) = foo();
```

And if you work with PHP 5.4, you can use array shortcut syntax here as well:

```
function foo54() {
    return [$firstArray, $secondArray];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think raina77ow's answer adequately answers your question. Another option to consider is to use write parameters.

```
function foobar(array &$arr1 = null)
{
    if (null !== $arr1) {
        $arr1 = array(1, 2, 3);
    }

    return array(4, 5, 6);
}
```

Then, to call:

```
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = foobar($arr1);
```

This won't be useful if you *always* need to return two arrays, but it can be used to always return one array and return the other only in certain cases.