# Return 2 values from a function

Tags: php, arrays, return, mediawiki

this is my first ever post on stackoverflow! I'm a mediawiki user and I'm trying to alter the [code](http://svn.wikimedia.org/svnroot/mediawiki/trunk/extensions/Autoincrement/) for the extension [Autoincrement](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAutoincrement), so that instead of outputting 1,2,3 it'll create text1, text2, text3 (with text being just some word in front of the number that the extension would normally create).

I've tried altering the Autoincrement.php file so that

```
function wfGroupHookSwitch( &$parser, &$varCache, &$index, &$ret ) {
    if ( $index === 'group' )
        $ret = ++$this->mCount; // No formatNum() just like url autonumbering

    return true;
}
```

looks something like

```
function wfGroupHookSwitch( &$parser, &$varCache, &$index, &$ret, &$text ) {
    if ( $index === 'group' )
        $text = 'sometexthere';
        $ret = ++$this->mCount; // No formatNum() just like url autonumbering

    return true;
}
```

but despite all the variations I try, nothing seems to work quite right. I'm a complete novice at php, so I'm just wondering, what would be the proper method of doing this?

Comment: I don't know this extension but if you just add a parameter nothing will happen outside because the rest of the code won't know anything about your &$text parameter. In fact this could even break code somewhere else.

Comment: How about you try to just prepend your text to the $ret variable like `$ret = 'sometexthere' . ++$this->mCount;`. This should work if $ret is treated as a string or just printed later in the code.

Comment: That worked, thank you!!

(Also, as I mentioned this is my first post, so I'm new to stackoverflow's way of doing things. Is there some way I should close the question or select a best answer?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple returns from function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to build a custom extension to do this. I would suggest getting

Variables:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Variables

and ParserFunctions:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions

Create Template:Autoincrement with this content:

```
<includeonly>{{#if: {{#var:AutoincrementVariable}}|{{#vardefineecho:AutoincrementVariable|{{#expr:{{#var:AutoincrementVariable}} + 1}} }}|{{#vardefineecho:AutoincrementVariable|1}} }}</includeonly>
```

Example usage and output from repeated template invocations should look like:

```
SomeText{{Autoincrement}}
SomeText{{Autoincrement}}
SomeText{{Autoincrement}}
```

produces

```
SomeText1
SomeText2
SomeText3
```