# Multiple return from a class function

Tags: php, oop

I am learning php OOP. While writing a class I am getting a logical problem that the function is not returning more than one value and I am just getting default value as output.
When I pass two variables in a function *setproperty()* and call back *getproperty()*, it returns only author's name. Here is the code:

```
class library{
    public $BookName="PHP OOP Programming";
    public $author="Faisal";

    public function setproperty($a_name,$b_name){
        $this->author=$a_name;
        //$this->BookName=$b_name;
    }

    public function getproperty(){
        return $this->author."<br />";
        //return $this->BookName."<br />";
    }
}
$obj=new library;
//var_dump($obj);

echo $obj->getproperty();
$obj->setproperty("naseer","SQL");
echo $obj->getproperty();
```

And I'm getting the output:

```
Faisal
naseer
```

Whereas the output I wanted is author's name along with books, much like:

```
Faisal
PHP OOP Programming

naseer
SQL
```

Comment: what's the point in `getproperty()` function?

Comment: use array to return the multiple values `return array($this->BookName, $this->author);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[Multiple returns from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-a-function)*

Answer (score 4):

You cannot return multiple times in a function.

If you need to return more than one value you can do something like:

```
return array('author'=>$this->author, 'bookName'=>$this->bookName);
```

And use it like this:

```
$res = $obj->getproperty();
echo "Author is ".$res['author'];
echo "Book is ".$res['bookName'];
```

You may want to change this depending on what the method is for/ how it will be used.

Answer (score 1):

A `return` statement is the end of any function. That's why a function is said *"to have returned"* when it's done doing whatever it needs to do. This isn't unique to OO, but to functions in *all* programming languages.
What you want to do is:

```
return $this->author.'<br/>'.$this->bookName.'<br/>';
```

Here, I'm concatenating all values into one string constant, and return that. This way, I have a single return value, and a single return statement with the desired output.
Like I said, even non-methods (regular functions) can't return more than 1 value - nor can they return *less* than 1 value:

```
function aFunction()
{
    echo '123';
}
```

Though lacking an *explicit* return:

```
$foo = 'not null';
$foo = aFunction();
var_dump($foo);//null!
```

the function clearly does return `null`, just like in C, a function that needn't return any value, returns `void`, or a JavaScript function returns `undefined`. The same applies to methods: they return null, implicitly or a single explicit return value.
You *could* write code like this, too:

```
function sillyFunction($someArgument = 1)
{
    return true;
    if ($someArgument < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ($someArgument === 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return $someArgument%2;
}
```

This function starts with a `return true;` statement. Any code that follows will never be reached, and thus never get executed, because this function has to *return* something to the caller, who then takes over again. You can't go back to the function and continue what you were doing there. A function is a one-go thing.

Workarounds: Thankfully, objects and arrays are regarded as a single value, so they can be returned from a function, and can contain multiple values. So that's the most common way to somehow get a function to return multiple values. The only, minor downside is that, once the function has returned, you have but a single access point for all these values: the variable to which you assigned the return value:

```
function foo()
{
    return array('foo' => range(1,100), 'bar' => range('A','Z'));
}
$foo = foo();
echo $foo['foo'][1], ' => ', $foo['bar'][1];//echoes 2 => B
```

In some *really rare* cases (in the past 10 years, I've needed this ~5 times) you *can* sort-of return several values using references:

```
function changeArrayAndReturn(array &$arrayRef)
{
    array_push($arrayRef, 'I was added in the function');//alters array
    return count($arrayRef);//AND returns int
}
$foo = array();
echo changeArrayAndReturn($foo);//echoes 1
$foo[] = 'I was added outside of the function';
echo changeArrayAndReturn($foo);//echoes 3
var_dump($foo);
//array(I was added in the function, I was added outside of the function, I was added in the function)
```

But that's dangerous and hard to maintain, so stay away, unless you *really* can't do it any other way

Comment: This is a very inflexible way of returning multiple values. The answer from Jim is better as the returned array can be used much easier.

Comment: @vascowhite: I was working on a more detailed answer, that includes arrays, objects, references and implicit returns. Besides, the concatenation was just taken from the OP's original snippet of code, where he returns a property, concatenated with `<br/>`, which also violates the single responsability principle, but this isn't the site for codereview

Answer (score 0):

A function stops when it encounters the first `return`. So it never gets to the line you commented out (even when it is not a comment).

```
public function getproperty()
{
  return $this->author."<br />".$this->BookName."<br />";
}
```

That way you display both values with a single `return`. You could also return an array if you preferred.

Comment: the same `echo $obj->getproperty();` you already had in your code.