# Returning multiple values from a function/method

Tags: php

I have a method in my class that I want to return more than one value:

```
public function lockFields($lockFieldsDBs, $lockValueConstant) {
    if ($lockFieldsDBs == $lockValueConstant) {
        $lockFieldValue = 'readonly="readonly"';
        $lockImage      = 'image_url_goes_here';
    }
    else {
        $lockFieldValue = null;
        $lockImage = null;
    }

    return $lockField;
    return $lockImage;
}


...........


$lockFieldsDBs = 'OK';
$lockValueConstant = 'OK';

$formHandler->lockFields($lockFieldsDBs, $lockValue);
```

When trying to print out a value like this: `echo $lockImage;`, I am getting `Undefined variable: lockImage`.

Why isn't the value being returned?

Comment: I guess that you can't return multiple variables

Comment: point 1: you miss to return anything if condition is true, point 2: you cant return 2 variables if you need both, return an array

Comment: The return is outside the if(), it's just bad formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple returns from function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return two or more values from a function with help of the `list()` language construct:

```
public function lockFields($lockFieldsDBs, $lockValueConstant) {
    if($lockFieldsDBs == $lockValueConstant){
        $lockFieldValue = 'readonly="readonly"';
        $lockImage = 'image_url_goes_here';
    }
    else {
        $lockFieldValue = null;
        $lockImage = null;
    }

    return [$lockField, $lockImage];
}



list($lockField, $lockImage) = $formHandler->lockFields($lockFieldsDBs, $lockValue);
```

Comment: Hi, should the list line in the class or the when I call the class. Thank you.

Comment: @ZYZ123ABC242526 Outside the class, right where you're calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are returning more than one variable form you function.
You can't. you have to assign an array or a list to do this job, to do this use either of these codes before ending your function:

```
return ['lockField'=>$lockField, 'lockImage'=>$lockImage];
```

or

```
return array($lockField, $lockImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only return one variable in a PHP function. If you need to return two, you need to use an array (or an object).

```
public function lockFields($lockFieldsDBs,$lockValueConstant)
{
    if($lockFieldsDBs == $lockValueConstant){
        $lockFieldValue = 'readonly="readonly"';
        $lockImage = 'image_url_goes_here';
    } else {
        $lockFieldValue = null;
        $lockImage = null;
    }
    return ['lockField'=>$lockField, 'lockImage'=>$lockImage];
}
```

Comment: Or `yield` but that gets a bit more complicated ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return two variables in a php function:

```
return $lockField;
return $lockImage;
```

You can put them in an array:

```
return array($lockField, $lockImage);
```

to use it:

```
$response = $formHandler->lockFields($lockFieldsDB,$lockValue)
echo $response[0]; // this is $lockField in your function 
echo $response[1]; // this is $lockImage in your function
```

Answer (score 0):

$lockImage is a variable inside of the method. Why do you think it will be available globally? To be clear:

```
public function lockFields($lockFieldsDBs,$lockValueConstant){
  $lockImage = "some value";
  return $lockImage;
}

$formHandler->lockFields($lockFieldsDB,$lockValue);
echo $lockImage; // variable $lockImage does not exists
```

won't work. It should be:

```
public function lockFields($lockFieldsDBs,$lockValueConstant){
  $lockImage = "some value";
  return $lockImage;
}

$lockImage = $formHandler->lockFields($lockFieldsDB,$lockValue);
echo $lockImage; // "some value"
```

The other answers point out that you need to return the value properly. But I think you also do not fetch the return correctly.