# How can we return multiple value from one function?

Tags: php

I am creating a simple web site in PHP, and I want to return multiple variables from one function. Is that possible or not?

And if possible, then how?

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask your question is incomplete. Anything is possible!

Comment: than say how it possible?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Define an object which semantically encapsulates those values into a meaningful structure.  Return an instance of that object.

Comment: It is also a duplicate of *[Multiple returns from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906)* (though that question is ambiguous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an array,

```
function doSth(){
    $a = 2;
    $b = 5
    $c = 9;
    return array($a, $b, $c);
}
```

and then use the `list()` method to get back single values:

```
list($a, $b, $c) = doSth();
echo $a; echo $b; echo $c;
```

Comment: Dang, just beat me to it!

Comment: There is also [destructuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Parallel_assignment) [in PHP 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48166310).

Answer (score 2):

Put them into an array:

```
function myFunction() {
    return array('name' => 'Joe', 'birthday' => '1976. 08. 29');
}
```

So after this, you can say:

```
$data = myFunction();
echo $data['name'] . "\n";
echo $data['birthday'];
```

If your array is not fixed, then you can loop through all of the keys and items:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . ": " . $value . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using arrays and the `list()` function:

```
function doSomething(){
  // do stuff
  return [$a, $b];
}

list($a, $b) = doSomething();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
< ?php

function multiple_returns()
{
    return array( 1, 2, "three" );
}

?>
```

Comment: How does this add to the three answers already given?

Comment: you will be pass by arguments