# Undefine index error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get two values 'total number of movies' and 'details of movies' from database.
For total number of movies, i am returning with php error "undefined_index:num_films".
please help me.

Sakila_control

```
<?php

class Sakila_control extends CI_Controller
{
    function display($offset=0)
    {
        $limit = 20;
        $this->load->model('films_model');
        $result = $this->films_model->search($limit,$offset);
        $data['films']=$result['rows'];
        $data['num_results']=$result['num_films'];



    $this->load->view('films_view',$data);

    }
    }
```

Films_model

```
<?php

class Films_model extends CI_Model
{
    function search($limit,$offset)
    {
       $qu = $this->
               db->select('FID,title,description,category,price,length,rating,actors')
                ->from('film_list')
                ->limit($limit,$offset);
       //rows comes from controller  
        $ret['rows']= $qu->get()->result();
        return $ret;


        $q = $this->db->select(`COUNT(*) as count`, FALSE)
                ->from('film_list');
        //num_rows comes from controller  
        $tmp= $q->get()->result();

       $ret['num_films']=$tmp[0]->count;

       return $ret;
    }
}
```

Films_view

```
<body>

        <table>
            <div>
                Found <?php echo $num_results;?> Films

            </div>
            <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>category</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>length</th>


            </thead>
            <tbody>


               <?php 
               foreach($films as $film):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $film->FID;?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $film->title;?></td>
                <!-- <td><?php echo $film->description;?></td> -->
                <td><?php echo $film->category;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $film->price;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $film->length;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $film->rating;?></td>
               <!-- <td><?php echo $film->actors;?></td> -->
            </tr>

            <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: return at last in function

Comment: What is the value of `$tmp` ?  Can you `var_dump($tmp);` so we can see the contents of it?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are returning the value just after the first query. So your function is not returning the `num_films`.

```
class Films_model extends CI_Model
{
    function search($limit,$offset)
    {
       $qu = $this->
               db->select('FID,title,description,category,price,length,rating,actors')
                ->from('film_list')
                ->limit($limit,$offset);
       //rows comes from controller  
        $ret['rows']= $qu->get()->result();
       // return $ret;


        $q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count`, FALSE)
                ->from('film_list');
        //num_rows comes from controller  
        $tmp= $q->get()->result();

       $ret['num_films']=$tmp[0]->count;

       return $ret;
    }
}
```

Check multiple return in same [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-function)

Comment: When i put at the end of function ,it gives another error

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$count
Filename: models/films_model.php
Line Number: 20

Comment: @zeeshanhaider: I updated my answer please check again. it is due to ```

Comment: @urfusioin
I removed ```` after reading your update code but it did not help me.

Comment: show your table. you can update that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to comment out this:

```
 // return $ret;
```

Then, you need to fix another error with backticks that you didn't get yet because of the return statement...

Backticks in PHP will attempt to run code from the command line.

Change this:

```
$q = $this->db->select(`COUNT(*) as count`, FALSE)
```

To this:

```
$q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
```

Final result:

```
<?php

class Films_model extends CI_Model
{
    function search($limit,$offset)
    {
       $qu = $this->
               db->select('FID,title,description,category,price,length,rating,actors')
                ->from('film_list')
                ->limit($limit,$offset);
       //rows comes from controller  
        $ret['rows']= $qu->get()->result();

        $q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
                ->from('film_list');
        //num_rows comes from controller  
        $tmp= $q->get()->result();

       $ret['num_films']=$tmp[0]->count;

       return $ret;
    }
}
```

Read more on backticks here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

> **Execution Operators**
>
> PHP supports one execution operator: backticks (``). Note that these are not single-quotes! PHP will attempt to execute the contents of the backticks as a shell command; the output will be returned (i.e., it won't simply be dumped to output; it can be assigned to a variable). Use of the backtick operator is identical to shell_exec().

Comment: when i put the code 
q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
                ->from('film_list');
it gave error
Message: Cannot access empty property

Filename: models/films_model.php

Line Number: 15

Answer (score 0):

What about this

**In Model**

```
class Films_model extends CI_Model
{
    function search($limit,$offset)
    {
        # Just pass all data to controller
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM film_list LIMIT $limit, $offset");
        $result = $query->result_array(); # Changed
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
class Sakila_control extends CI_Controller
{
    function display()
    {
        $limit = 20;
        $offset=0

        $this->load->model('films_model');
        $data['films'] = $this->films_model->search($limit,$offset);

        $count = count($data['films']); # get count on here 
        $data['num_results'] = $count;
        $this->load->view('films_view',$data);
    }
}
```

**In View**

All Fine and its up to you

Comment: in view count should come as `$num_results`

Comment: After your modifications, i get error
Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result_array()

Filename: models/films_model.php

Comment: oopz wait small mistake

Comment: @zeeshanhaider check now

Comment: no dude .
it just returned 0 film and only displayed heading row

Comment: below data reciving??

Comment: In view table data is reciving??

Comment: data is handling properly in view as it was before.
In controller , the output of below line is
$data['films'] = $this->films_model->search($limit,$offset);
        print_r($data);
Array() => 0

Comment: Your view is correct. Chaek table name and inside having data

Comment: table name is film_list and data is also correct :(

Comment: @zeeshanhaider remove limit and ofset in Model and try

Comment: returned true number of films i-e 997 but also reurnrd 997 error boxes with the same error

Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: views/films_view.php