# php - find match in string

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to work out how to find a match in a string.
I'm looking for a match on any of the following  `- = ? [] ~ # ! 0 - 9 A-Z a-z` and I need to know what its matched on .

Eg: matched on `!`, or matched on `=` and `#` and `?`

Normally I'd use this:

```
$a = 'How are you?';

if (strpos($a, 'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

However I'm not sure how to do that so it looks up the characters needed.
Also where I may have `[]`, It could be `[]` or `[xxxx]`  where xxxx could be any number of alpha numeric characters.

I need to match and any of the characters listed, return the characters so I know what was matched and if the [] contain any value return that as well.

Eg:

`$a = 'DeviceLocation[West12]';`
Would return: `$match = '[]'; $match_val= 'West12';`

`$a = '#=Device';`
Would return:`$match = '#,=';`

`$a=  '?[1234]=#Martin';`
Would return: `$match = '?, [], =, #'; $match_val= '1234';`

Can any one advise how I can do this.
Thanks

Comment: `DeviceLocation[West12]` what do you want to find in this string ?

Comment: Try `if (preg_match('/[][A-Za-z0-9!#~?=-]/', $str, $m)) { echo "Matched: " . $m[0]; }`

Comment: @OwaisArain - I'd want to match on the [] and if possible grab the value from between.

Comment: So, you only need the string between square brackets? See https://ideone.com/8L3naA

Comment: I need to match and any of the characters listed, return the characters so I know what was matched and if the [] contain any value return that as well.

Comment: Then see https://ideone.com/yD6l31

Comment: That just shows 'D' - I've updated my answer with some examples.

Comment: Of course it ouptuts `D` because it matches *any of the characters listed*. You forgot to add the expected output for each input.

Comment: I've updated the original question with examples and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that requirements are a bit vague, but that is what I deduced:

1) if there is an alphanumeric string inside square brackets get it as a separate value
 2) all other mentioned chars should be matched one by one and then `implode`d.

You may use the following regex to get the values you need:

```
$re = '@\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]|[][=?~#!]@';
```

*Details*:

- `\[` - a `[`
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` - Group 1 value capturing 1 or more alphanumeric symbols
- `\]` - a closing `]`
- `|` - or
- `[][=?~#!]` - a single char, one of the defined chars in the set.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/69GQsk/1). The most important here is the code that gets the matches (feel free to adapt):

```
$re = '@\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]|[][=?~#!]@';
$strs =array('DeviceLocation[West12]', '#=Device', '?[1234]=#Martin');

foreach ($strs as $str) {
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $results = array();
    $match_val = "";
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        if (!empty($m[1])) {
            $match_val = trim($m[1], "[]");
            array_push($results, "[]");
        } else {
            array_push($results, $m[0]);
        } 
    }
    echo "Value: " . $match_val . "\n";
    echo "Symbols: " . implode(", ", $results);
    echo "\n-----\n";
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/TqZiOe)

Output:

```
Value: West12
Symbols: []
-----
Value: 
Symbols: #, =
-----
Value: 1234
Symbols: ?, [], =, #
-----
```

Comment: that looks perfect.  Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to turn this into a function. How do I return the Value and Symbols separately ?

Comment: You may return an array. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-function.

Comment: Just thought of one other possible scenario.. `[Device]=test` Is there anyway to get the word test as well in a new variable ?

Comment: If you mean you want to get chunks of word chars as yet another variable,  you may try adding another capture group alternative `(\w+)`. See https://ideone.com/OfBfK4. Note how the output also changes for other test strings.

Comment: wow.. thanks. looking at that symbols is always the symbols found. Val 1 is the value from the brackets and val2 is other text.. That will work. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Please use Regular Expressions, e.g using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

It will match the string in `[]`

```
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $text, $matches);
```

And this will match string after `?` and `#=`

```
preg_match_all("/^#=(\S+)|\?(.*)/", $text, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: OP does not need to extract all texts inside square brackets. See the question: *Eg: matched on `!`, or matched on `=` and `#` and `?`*

Answer (score 0):

You need [regular expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm) to check for any text inside another with different properties, here is a simple tutorial on that link.