# Cookie check in OOP

Tags: php, oop

Until yesterday I was burning my brain trying to switch from a procedural thinking to a OOP thinking; this morning I gave up. I said to my self I wasn't probably ready yet to understand it.

I started then coding in the usual way, writing a function to check if there's the cookie "logged" or not

```
function chkCookieLogin() {
if(isset($_COOKIE["logged"])) {
    $logged = 'true';
    $cookieValue = $_COOKIE["logged"];

    return $logged;
    return $cookieValue;
}
else {
    $logged = 'false';

    return $logged;
}
}

$result = chkCookieLogin();
if($result == 'true'){
    echo $cookieValue;
}
else {
    echo 'NO COOKIE';
}
```

since I run across a problem: I wanted to return two variables (`$logged` and `$cookieValue`) instead of just one. I google it and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579950/6465600) where Jasper explains a method using an OOP point of view (or this is what I can see).
That answer opened me a new vision on the OOP so I tried to rewrite what I was trying to achieve this way:

```
class chkCookie {
public $logged;
public $cookieValue;

public function __construct($logged, $cookieValue) {
    $this->logged = $logged;
    $this->cookieValue = $cookieValue;
}

function chkCookieLogin() {
    $out = new chkCookie();
    if(isset($_COOKIE["logged"])) {
        $out->logged = 'true';
        $out->cookieValue = $_COOKIE["logged"];

        return $out;
    }
    else {
        $out->logged = 'false';

        return $out;
    }
}
}

$vars = chkCookieLogin();
$logged = $vars->logged;
$cookieValue = $vars->cookieValue;
echo $logged; echo $cookieValue;
```

Obviously it didn't work at the first attempt...and neither at the second and the third. But for the first time I feel I'm at one step to "really touch" the OOP (or this is what I think!).

My questions are:

1. is this attempt correctly written from the OOP point of view?
2. If yes, what are the problems? ('cause I guess there's more than one)

Thank you so much!

Comment: That's a horrible way of doing it... Go back to procedural for this, and note that you can `return array("logged" => $logged, "cookieValue" => $cookieValue);`

Comment: I think that the friends on codereview can help you better on this one, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol End but apart for the specific case of the cookie check, did I go close to the OOP thinking or not? 'Cause for me try to switch from one to another method has the same feeling of walking blindfolded in a dark room: I've 0 certainities!

Comment: @Federkun thanks for the tip! I even didn't know about its existence!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Credit to [@NiettheDarkAbsol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol) for the idea of returning an Array data-type.

---

Using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), you can set-up an object like this:

```
class Factory {
    private $Data = [];
    public function set($index, $data) {
        $this->Data[$index] = $data;
    }

    public function get($index) {
        return $this->Data[$index];
    }
}
```

Then to use the DI module, you can set methods like so (using [anonymous functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)):

```
$f = new Factory();
$f->set('Cookies', $_SESSION);
$f->set('Check-Cookie', function() use ($f) {
    return $f->get('Cookies')['logged'] ? [true, $f->get('Cookies')['logged']] : [false, null];
});
```

Using error checks, we can then call the method when and as we need it:

```
$cookieArr = is_callable($f->get('Check-Cookie')) ? call_user_func($f->get('Check-Cookie')) : [];
echo $cookieArr[0] ? $cookieArr[1] : 'Logged is not set';
```

---

I'd also consider adding constants to your DI class, allowing more dynamic approaches rather than doing error checks each time. IE, on `set()` include a constant like `Factory::FUNC_ARRAY` so your `get()` method can return the closure already executed.

You can look into using [ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) if you're confused.

See it working over at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/k5mk9). 
If it means anything, [here is an OOP styled approach.](https://3v4l.org/et9v9)

Comment: Ok, when I grow up I wanna be like you. It's so different and ways more complicated compared to the "(bad) style" I code now that I feel like a baby! I'm gonna study your script word by word to get deep into it 'cause it's fascinating

Comment: Haha, glad I could help. @brigo

Comment: I'm not sure why this is a good answer. The `Factory` class is just an array here. Just because there's the word "class" somewhere doesn't mean that this isn't a procedural code.

Comment: Don't ruin his vibe ;) here is an [OOP approach](https://3v4l.org/et9v9) if it suits better @Federkun