# Multiple return of one function

Tags: php, function, return

I'm using the function:

```
function findTeamFromID($teams,$ID) {
    $results = array_column($teams, 'langform', 'id_teams');
    return (isset($results[$ID])) ? $results[$ID] : FALSE;
};
```

Now i want not only to replace the ID with the name, it should write a link to the detail page. I don't wanted to touch the return line so i made this:

```
function findTeamFromID($teams,$ID) {
    $results = array_column($teams, 'langform', 'id_teams');
    return "<a href=\"details.php?id=".$ID."\">";
    return (isset($results[$ID])) ? $results[$ID] : FALSE;
    return "</a>";
};
```

Funny now is, that Return 1 and 3 appear and the href will be correctly created. But the second return doesn't appear anymore.

What did i make wrong?

Comment: Everything. It is impossible to return multiple things in php. First thing returns. Maybe the third thing is "returned" because it auto completes the tag. Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple returns from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hints. So i found the solution by myself.

```
    function findTeamFromID($teams,$ID) {
        $results = array_column($teams, 'langform', 'id_teams');
        return "<a href=\"details.php?id=".$ID."\">".
        (isset($results[$ID]) ? $results[$ID] : FALSE). "</a>";
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot have multi return value from php function. In your code, only the first return statement works.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Learned something new :-) How the pros solves a "problem" like mine?

Comment: I would just concatenate it with dots. You are even doing it in first return near ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote in result
EDIT:

```
  function findTeamFromID($teams,$ID) {
        $results = array_column($teams, 'langform', 'id_teams');
        return "<a href=\"details.php?id=".$ID."\">".
       (isset($results[$ID]) ? $results[$ID] : FALSE)
       . "</a>";
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. But still empty :(