# Can we use multiple return with single function?

Tags: php

My question is can we return multiple return query with single function and call them?

for example:

```
<?php 
function addition($a, $b, $c, $d)
{
    $x = $a+$b+$c+$d;
    $y = $a+$b;
    $z = $c+$d;
    return $x;
    return $y;
    return $z;
}
?>
```

Can we call the function and get the value of `$x`, `$y`, `$z` all together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple returns from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-a-function)

Comment: Yeah got it. 
I was just wondering how can i return multiple value.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do, you can only do return once in the function. when ever a return is executed you take the control back from the function and it stops further execution of the function. you could write multiple returns under conditional statements but only one return will be executed.

```
function addition($a, $b, $c, $d)
{
    $x = $a+$b+$c+$d;
    $y = $a+$b;
    $z = $c+$d;

    $arr = [
        'x' => $x,
        'y' => $y,
        'z' => $z,
    ];
    return $arr;
}

// you can get the values like this

$res = addition($a, $b, $c, $d);

echo $res['x'];
echo $res['y'];
echo $res['z'];
```