# Return conditional on method using array and/or object

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a single method that generated a cache key and also applies a transient automatically.

Here is the method:

```
private function get_cache($id, $count)
{
    $cache_key = $this->generate_cache_key($id, $count);

    return get_transient($cache_key);
}
```

How could I make that method return both the `$cache_key` but also `get_transient`?

**Here is what I'm trying to achieve**:

- Access the $cache_key inside another method.
- Also execute the get_transient when calling the method.

I have a method and this is what I'm aiming to achieve:

```
public function delete_cache($count = 4)
    {
        $cache_key = $this->get_cache['cache_key'];
        var_dump($cache_key);
    }
```

So I was thinking something like `$instagram->get_cache['cache_key']` but also keep the original functionality for:

```
if ($cached = $instagram->get_cache($instagram->user_id, $count)) {
    return $cached;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the cache_key for another method, but still keep the get_transient return?

Comment: You could simply return an array with 2 values, like `return [$cache_key, get_transient($cache_key)];` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple returns from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451906/multiple-returns-from-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of returning multiple values from a function is called a "tuple". Almost every language implements this to some degree, sometimes as a "record", sometimes as a "database row", or maybe as a struct. For PHP, you are pretty much limited to either an object with fields, or an array, with the latter being the most common. Your `get_cache` function could be reworked as:

```php
    private function get_cache($id, $count)
    {
        $cache_key = $this->generate_cache_key($id, $count);

        return [$cache_key, get_transient($cache_key)];
    }
```

And to invoke it you'd do:

```php
[$cache_key, $value] = $this->get_cache('a', 4);
```

Or, if using an older version of PHP (or you just don't like the look of that):

```php
list($cache_key, $value) = $this->get_cache('a', 4);
```

The downside of this is that **all** callers have to be changed to support this, which may or may not be a problem. An alternative is to add an optional callback to the function that performs more work:

```php
    private function get_cache($id, $count, callable $func = null)
    {
        $cache_key = $this->generate_cache_key($id, $count);

        $value = get_transient($cache_key);

        if(is_callable($func)){
            $func($cache_key, $value);
        }

        return $value;
    }
```

And call it like:

```php
$value = $this->get_cache(
        'a',
        4,
        static function($cache_key, $value) {
            var_dump($cache_key);
        }
    );
```

Although you are using WordPress, I think it is helpful to see what other frameworks do, too. [PSR-6](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-6/) defines something called `CacheItemInterface` which is the object-form of the return, and [Symfony's cache](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html#cache-component-contracts) (which you can actually use in WordPress, I do sometimes on large projects) uses the get-with-callback syntax.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris! This is super helpful, will be testing it out now.

Answer (score 0):

You could return an array of those two values

```php
private function get_cache($id, $count)
{
    $cache_key = $this->generate_cache_key($id, $count);

    return [$cache_key, get_transient($cache_key)];
}

// ...

[$cache_key, $transient] = get_cache($id, $count);
```

Comment: Beat me by 13 seconds!

Comment: @Chris Haas, ;)

Comment: Thanks so much Bruno! This is super helpful, will be testing it out now.

Comment: You're welcome @Trippp, have a nice evening!